# What are the fixed point(s) of this mapping?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given the mapping $\operatorname{A} \colon C[0;1] \rightarrow C[0;1]$ (functions which are continuous over a given interval)

$\operatorname{A}x(t) = x^2(t)-x(t)-t^2;$

What are the fixed point(s)?

---

Assuming the apparently default metric $d(x(t),y(t)) = \max_{0 \le t \le 1} |x(t)-y(t)|$ this won't be a contraction mapping hence an iterative procedure cannot be used (I'm referring to [Banach fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem)).

I am very rusty on this subject so some suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What does $x^2(t)$ mean? $(x(t))^2$ or $x(x(t))$?

Comment: @gerw This simply meant $(x(t))^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2(t)-x(t)-t^2=x(t),$$
hence
$$(x(t)-1)^2=t^2+1,$$
which gives
$$|x(t)-1|=\sqrt{t^2+1}.$$
Then we obtain two different solutions,
$$x_1(t)=1+\sqrt{t^2+1},\quad x_2(t)=1-\sqrt{t^2+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know that a fixed point must satisfy $x(t) = x(t)^2 - x(t) - t^2$.  Solve this for $x(t)$ to get $x(t) = 1 \pm \sqrt{1 + t^2}$.  There are exactly two continuous functions described by that formula.